# Redis INFO Shows Calls to DEL But No Code Calls DEL

Tags: logging, redis, command, del

We are sometimes missing Data in Redis so I ran the INFO Command for our Redis instance. I was surprised to see calls to the DEL Command in the hundred thousands, because we do not have code that executes the DEL Command:

```
# Commandstats
cmdstat_del:calls=971486,usec=776218,usec_per_call=0.80
```

I read on this [redis article](https://redis.io/topics/replication) that:

```
Slaves don't expire keys, instead they wait for masters to expire the keys.
When a master expires a key (or evict it because of LRU),
it synthesizes a DEL command which is transmitted to all the slaves.
```

We do have lots of Expired Keys, although it is not as high as the number of calls to the DEL Command:

```
# Stats
expired_keys:56220
```

Could this be the reason why there are so many calls to the DEL Command even when our codes do not execute the DEL Command?

Comment: An expiration is viewed as DEL, and also OOM eviction, do you have that configured maybe?